# Haskell: Count the occurrences of the characters in a string for every character

Tags: string, haskell, count, character

countCharacterOccurences :: String -> [(Char, Int)]

I'm trying to make a function that will return a list of all the characters in the string along with the amount of times they are included.

For example:

countCharacterOccurences "happy" = [('h', 1), ('a', 1), ('p', 2), ('y', 1)]

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi, thank you for the response.  I'm very new to Haskell, so not much at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

This will do it

```
map (\x -> (head x, length x)) $ group $ sort theString
```

Note, you will need to import Data.List.

Comment: Thank you, I will try this.

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with some of the errors.  For example, the compiler is saying "Not in scope 'sort'"  "Not in scope 'group'"

Comment: You need to import something, I've added this to the answer.

Comment: Thanks again!  So i am able to get this to work at the command line in ghci,however, how would I get this into a function?  I've tried something like: "countCharacters str = map (\x -> (head x, length x)) $ group $ sort str" but I had no luck

Comment: That should work, what error are you getting.  Note, you still need the `import Data.List` at the top of the file.  I copied your code directly and it worked for me.